# Index was outside the bounds of the array in a for loop C#

Tags: c#

So I've been woking a Console game for a while now and I desided to use .txt files to hold the maps. This code opens and stores the txt file contents:

```
        static void LoadMap(string fname)
    {
        string _org = File.ReadAllText("Maps/" + fname + ".txt");
        _org.Split(',');
        string[] _tmp = new string[_org.Length];
        for (int i=0;i<_org.Length;i++)
        {
            _tmp[i] = _org[i].ToString();
        }
        //This line has the error
        for (int i=0;_tmp[i]!="$";i+=2)
        {
            mapwidth += 1;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<_tmp.Length;i++)
        {
            leveldata.Add(_tmp[i]);
        }
    }
```

I get this error: Index was outside the bounds of the array. I can't figgure out why. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: You are aware that you are incrementing your indexer by 2 ever time, right? If you have 5 objects in the _tmp array, the fourth loop will error out since it would be _tmp[0], _tmp[2], _tmp[4], _tmp[6] (doesn't exist thus outside the bounds of the array).

Comment: The line `for (int i=0;_tmp[i]!="$";i+=2)` isn't checking the bounds on `_tmp` so it could easily have the index go out of bounds, and clearly it does. Something isn't right with your assumption of the contents of `_tmp`, but you haven't shown what that is so we can't help you more than saying it's obviously here.

Comment: Also, is the call to the method String.Split intended for the _org object?, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not super sure what you are getting at here but I feel a `foreach` may be a step in the right direction.

First, here are a few things I noticed in the code you presented.

```
    string _org = File.ReadAllText("Maps/" + fname + ".txt");
    _org.Split(',');
```

Here you have ingested your text file and split `_org` with a comma delimiter. Though you never actually assigned the split array to a variable. `_org` is still a `string`, not a `string[]`.

```
    string[] _tmp = new string[_org.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < _org.Length; i++)
    {
        _tmp[i] = _org[i].ToString();
    }
```

In this block we have set `_tmp` as a string array using the length of `_org`. The `Length` property in this case will retrieve the number of characters in the string `_org`. assuming `_org` is set to `"foo"` the size of the `_tmp`array is now 3. (0,1,2)

You then go on to load `_tmp` with the nth character of `_org` converted to a string.

At this point we have the following in our variables.

```
_org = "foo"
_tmp = {"f","o","o"}
```

This next part caught me a bit off guard as I cant tell for certain what you are trying to accomplish.

```
    for (int i = 0; _tmp[i] != "$"; i += 2)
    {
        mapwidth += 1;
    }
```

You are in a for loop until `_tmp[i]` equals `"$"`, and you are adding `2` to `i` every time you move through the loop using `i += 2`. This logic will break the loop until it hits a `"$"`, or if `i` grows outside of the bounds of the array it will throw an exception.

You then go on to add one to the `mapwidth` for every two increments of `i`

In this final block you are adding the contents of the `_tmp` array to `leveldata`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _tmp.Length; i++)
    {
        leveldata.Add(_tmp[i]);
    }
```

Now for the good stuff, `foreach`.
I have made the assumption you wanted to set _org as an array, and that you wanted everything that was not a "$". That in mind, this should accomplish what you were going for, though I am not sure the purpose of incrementing by 2 in the second for loop so I have left that out for now.

```
static void LoadMap(string fname)
{

    string[] _org = File.ReadAllText("Maps/" + fname + ".txt").Split(',');

    foreach (var _tmp in _org)
    {

        if (_tmp != "$")
        {
            mapwidth += 1;
        }

        leveldata.Add(_tmp);
    }
}
```

If you want to continue coding it is always a good idea to get a good grasp on the basics.

Though a bit dated here is a good tutorial by Microsoft for programming basics in C#: 
[C# Programmer's Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks this is want I needed Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check that variable `i` does not take values beyond the `Length - 1` of the array.

```
static void LoadMap(string fname)
{
    string _org = File.ReadAllText("Maps/" + fname + ".txt");

    _org.Split(',');

    string[] _tmp = new string[_org.Length];

    for (int i = 0;i < _org.Length; i++)
    {
        _tmp[i] = _org[i].ToString();
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < _tmp.Length && _tmp[i] != "$"; i += 2)
    {
        mapwidth += 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < _tmp.Length; i++)
    {
        leveldata.Add(_tmp[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this link.

https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/foreach-loop

Have suggestion keyword to avoid **Index was outside the bounds of the array** error.

Sample code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
   {
        // Coding to Array for loop.
   }
```